# SEARCH QUERY PLEASE HELP | call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback php

Tags: wp-query, functions, hooks

Major issue with my search queries being outputted incorrectly on the blog page with respect to query's. In wordpress admin most relevant listed first but outputted DESC on page.

I have this code in funtions,php

```
function change_posts_order( $query ) {
if ( $query-is_home() && $query-is_main_query() ) {
$query-set( 'orderby', 'title' );
$query-set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
}
```

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', ' change_posts_order ' );

Bt it does not work - I have removed all plugins on page except jetpack and akismet: Still no joy. PhP returns these related errors:[image: php error message]

please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You have extra spaces around `change_posts_order`, inside the quotes:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', ' change_posts_order ' );
```

PHP can’t find a function with that name, because wits looking for that function preceded with the spaces. Remove the spaces to fix the issue:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_posts_order' );
```

Comment: thankyou for that and well spotted! I think it might have solved the issue indeed, the PHP warning has gone but it is a little hard to tell - some queries return the same and others as they should. Does SQL cache queries at all because it seems past queries are returned false and newer ones as they should be. I have purged server and browser cache and search in incog so it looks like a caching issue now is responsible for these mixed results... a little more investigation needed my end but happy to have removed the PHP warning and appearing to get on track here - thanks

Comment: It's probably not working at all. `$query-is_home()` and `$query-is_main_query()` are missing the `>`. They need to be `$query->is_home()` and `$query->is_main_query()`. So the ones that worked were probably just a coincidence.

Comment: thanks for this but still same issue - are posts and custom post types dealt considered the same? or do I need to change the function taxonomy? apologies, I am a real novice and your help is highly appreciated